# Function not receiving var as string

Tags: javascript, php

Tengo un `foreach` para serverside datatables que me da problemas a la hora de insertar un var js en string para la función `copyToClipboard();`. ¿Habría forma de insertar la var en string con `''` de esta forma?

```
foreach($tutores as $row){
    $contactos.='<div class="btn-group dropup"><button style="margin-bottom:5px;" type="button" class="btn btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">'.$row['nombre'].' '.$row['apellidos'].' <span class="caret"></span></button><span class="dropdown-arrow"></span>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    ';
    if (!empty($row['email']) AND $row['email'] != "0") {
            $contactos.='<li><a href="javascript:(void)" style="cursor:not-allowed; color:#218f00;"><b><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> '.$row['email'].'</b></a></li><li><a href="mailto:'.$row['email'].'"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i> Enviar Email</a></li>
            '; 
            $contactos.= "<li><a href='#' onClick='copyToClipboard('".$row['email']."');'><i class='fa fa-clipboard'></i> Copiar Email</a></li>";
    } else {
                    
    }
    $contactos.='</ul></div><br>';
                
}
```

El problema sería que esta línea: `onClick='copyToClipboard('".$row['email']."');'` acaba en el html: `onclick="copyToClipboard(email);"` no como debería de acabar, con los `''` para la var en string. `onclick="copyToClipboard('email');"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que yo haría es asegurar el string, las comillas se mezclan y eso suele dar lugar a fallos difíciles de detectar. En el código HTML usa las comillas dobles, para la cadena php usa comillas simples y escapa las comillas simples que tienen que aparecer en la cadena:

```
$contactos.= '<li><a href="#" onClick="copyToClipboard(\''.$row['email'].'\');"><i class="fa fa-clipboard"></i> Copiar Email</a></li>';
```

Comment: Lo he solucionado de esta forma. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

```javascript
onclick='copyToClipboard(`$row['email']`);'
```

Tienes que estar usando comillas dobles, porque el onclick usa la simple, asi que adjuntamos unas `` dentro de la funcion para hacerlo mas legible, PHP agregara la variable por si sola.

Comment: He probado así pero tampoco genera bien el html, sigue generandose asi: <a href="#" onclick="copyToClipboard(email@haus36.de);"><i class="fa fa-clipboard"></i> Copiar Email</a>

Comment: Mil disculpas, es onclick=\"copyToClipboard(\"$row['email']\")\"